# Configuring SSH to push to GitHub fails

Tags: git, github, ssh

I went through the process of generating ssh keys and submitting the public key to github.  I was able to push to my github repo last night.  But today at work I had to push to my company repo and perhaps that screwed something up because when I now go to push to the same repo I could push to last night I get

```
ERROR: Permission to ME/this-site-2017.git denied to myUserName.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

if I `cat` `~/.ssh/` I see:

> github1       github1.pub (among other files)

I uploaded the public key to github last night and I still see it there.

So my question is what happened?  Why do I no longer have permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authentication key does not need to be only in `~/.ssh`, but `ssh` needs to know about it, for example using configuration file `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github1
```

Comment: will this harm any of my other ssh/git configurations?  I'm having trouble understanding the file-system architecture of ssh and how that relates to my various ssh contracts with remote servers.  for example, when told to generate new ssh keys on github or elsewhere, i'm told to `ssh-keygen` which simply creates a new `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`.  but is that not just one public-private keypair intended to be used for the one remote server connection?  similarly, in your answer it seems that its instructing only one key to be used as some primary key.  i'm not really understanding whats going on

Comment: Generally it should not be needed to generate more than one key. If you wish to generate more keys, they needs to be named different that the default (id_*) and they need to be assigned to specific service, where you are going to use them (eg, github) as proposed in the answer.

Comment: ah so the reason that there is but one pub/priv key pair in ~/.ssh is because its intended to hold one private key and use the corresponding public one for all of your ssh connections?

Comment: my config now looking like:
`Host *
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 UseKeychain yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github1`

still fails permission

Comment: yes. One file pair (priv, pub) is holding one private key pair.

Comment: You probably have the other key (`id_rsa`) assigned to other github account which does not have access to that repository.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148059/discussion-between-alex-bollbach-and-jakuje).